# Error building Angular Library : Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: angular8, angular-library

I have created a custom library to be used in my main angular application...

However, when I try to build the library using ng build lib-name I am getting the error:

`**Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined**.`

I could not find an exact solution to get rid of this error.
Any suggested actions?

Some reference information:

Angular CLI: 8.3.5
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

```
Package                      Version

@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.5
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.5
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.5
@schematics/angular          8.3.5
@schematics/update           0.803.5
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having exactly the same error.

Comment: No I did not find any solution.... I skipped using the library method altogether ...I am now creating separate components in my project.

Comment: I think there is an issue with schemantics and angular 8. So i deleted it from my library dependences and now it's working.

Comment: could you give a short walkthrough of how you managed it? I could then try the same. thanks!

Comment: which components are you using in your library? Then i also need your dependences in the angular workspace and your library peer dependences and i will reproduce it. I solved it just starting again from the scratch and adding the dependences one by one

Comment: Have you worked with ngx dashboards framework?                                                     https://github.com/catalogicsoftware/ngx-dynamic-dashboard-framework/blob/master/README.md I was trying to convert this into a library and use it for my project.

Comment: I did the same with ApexCharts to make my own charts library. Let me see the dependences in your workspace and the peer dependencies in your library. And algo how are you importing in your library in app.modules.ts

Answer (score 0):

For me, I get this because I prefer inline templates and styles but I forget to include -s -t flags when using ng generate (especially in lib projects where the global inline settings in angular.json don't seem to stick?).

After I do an ng generate I delete the foo.html and foo.scss files to avoid going into a trance while alt-tabbing 20 times in 5 seconds.

Then, I change templateUrl to template: `<p>foo works</p>` (note: replace the single quotes from the url string with the template's tickmarks).

I then often forget to change the styleUrl['foo.scss'] to styles:[``] and then this error message pops up.  This is quite a lame error message from a great tool but I thinks it has something to do with the opacity of webpack.